# Scrapy 403 error (but no error with http.client.HTTPSConnection using Insomnia

Tags: python, https, scrapy, http-headers, web-crawler

I am trying to convert my api crawler into a Scrapy api crawler, but I'm getting a 403 error in scrapy only.
2022-01-29 11:48:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <POST [https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post/>](https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post/%3E) (referer: https://www.realtor.ca/)

What am I doing wrong on scrapy side? I used Insomnia to generate the working POST request. But scrapy can't seem to handle it, and I don't know why.

Working code:

```
import http.client
import json
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api2.realtor.ca")

payload = "ZoomLevel=11&LatitudeMax=43.98268&LongitudeMax=-78.96028&LatitudeMin=43.43223&LongitudeMin=-79.79249&Sort=6-D&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&Currency=CAD&CurrentPage=1&ApplicationId=1&CultureId=1&Version=7.0&RecordsPerPage=200"

headers = {
    'cookie': "gig_bootstrap_3_mrQiIl6ov44s2X3j6NGWVZ9SDDtplqV7WgdcyEpGYnYxl7ygDWPQHqQqtpSiUfko=gigya-pr_ver4; visid_incap_2271082=JLYUNoQeQ8aK7XCukUKVyLTR4GEAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD5E9h/kC3MKXYFk8j751oC; reese84=3:kSScWfkGFsGrIfH0oClFcA==:7I6p2X8egFPYsN4vhOQSzcG+bY31pkxS/fXEEvP9k7YrM9pKJIRxaMywKm1+U1DhuZilDxW9dT97UvcEqz9H8d6b81yJvbuEOsNCc1hlGdVd3ZjT2uSjne23lT3z3KZ2lj0sxMQRKgafW63RLwfBQWtCgxWHMp9k338xzLwnTwqzOMI+qkBLPMwUolKoJP3IL6gzbljA6PY7Pyaa/R7VMRlGzcnk+M/ILnqZV8kJ+xV8sukeGZAcs4nJqJbvRr6vSE+fsAe/Jct5iAOnYTGoC+IyUdOAIWn2jEXTjwdjndvGdsKGvvkvcnkIjX1/JNTFH922HZPL3q9LzFCEgMhuYgygFRFjCqaz/HJ0zr0DXL9uTjiripD29T9lA0k0fGs+vyMz0ApV2Ni9UJsosr747CQMLROcZCQSIik2p+Taflc3cIAZgituGSiJss6o94xm:40hT11A7LacDXW+pa+D9sBQF5meDdTDqnBCeCZs/jls=; visid_incap_2269415=SnrfkV/xRM2/zMAwUwhS+8xj4GEAAAAAQkIPAAAAAACALOWhAWPmyCDb18oF6pHY12yEiWlUbIgr; nlbi_2269415=Vq3lX/59Tg3xXSVkkG5lugAAAAB+8mCpAlS1F5Timw4irGua; _gid=GA1.2.1583316853.1643415717; ASP.NET_SessionId=ov1iizcd3npobsilupzii5ep; nlbi_2271082=uYrYPyycJwjJZMEUcbDG1QAAAABYkXBfZhGO2s/HVfvOZarc; incap_ses_303_2269415=tkGkDvUztDFYLuufDHk0BPFK9WEAAAAAaFTGABendGhY7YQ6DfHGqg==; incap_ses_303_2271082=R007Dwk7akm7gfCfDHk0BPhS9WEAAAAAEzSDycWG9SwrHnLXWGiOuQ==; reese84=3:xy6Z/sx1YkpUszEJSoRL3A==:lovsunYlSfQpJkP59Bs11wY2+LlgzOMeiL3ObotvVpDwGDJVy4RKfSLLKuvVMLLcTstWzewelf4RKJ3e6v5hAVv9wkqa01hiSd1TIDBTDdyPzcKMI0xlq6r0G2P+8dMx91eZ0jKEx40QdURnU3XwLghg1BALZ+aWt4US7pC1FIftQksLhz7QlnyBw8pl2ucIJ9JIyuM3gBjNaP4hvYyc17UOnBvf37wtLhWeFb+fomUnnLqyTag5dM/vASoIg+Uo+lH9yQI2K9xGm0KveqgF2nUre9Z+UG1gwHWRBEIjygnhZZjnJOR20wxQU7gOZ8YqW+DJdczgSiqbn93I1um+VwOlf8bD6zCq99miEtaVOdVlGZesCvoe9d9JciEryAFMlYcn3RuLvycVNPQVrdCP9REneI+J1AmfXeSveEGpLhnSZs64rniGIf7iT0lRY9c1:f519Rour27xdzG5PjxP0BlHw/5uwjBdnwdY9Zd3AWpU=; nlbi_2269415_2147483646=5DLdcUXrjg0v1GhykG5lugAAAAA0AOEmZsShmR8VQ3d3LJzx; _dc_gtm_UA-12908513-11=1; _ga=GA1.2.2104488426.1642095581; _gac_UA-12908513-11=1.1643468700.Cj0KCQiA6NOPBhCPARIsAHAy2zAmFT3_yol1CanQDHoHW_z8aJ6HgaY2f7iilRt6yGvssuzmDbbh8FoaAkpxEALw_wcB; _ga_Y07J3B53QP=GS1.1.1643467388.20.1.1643468729.19; _4c_=%7B%22_4c_s_%22%3A%22bZNbj5swEIX%2FSuTnhfgKJm%2BrVKpWatWqUp8jgwdiLcHIOKHbKP%2B9Y3JZ7ap%2BAZ85%2BoxnDmcy72EgG1ZIIQtdCiGUfiKv8DaRzZkEZ9PjRDakrUBWitqsVIxmEjjNdNGYzIAxFFdbcUmeyJ%2BFVemSKc2oKi5PxA53hoXWHPt4tymqpZaSCS3Q5sZ486WPYVJrWWquH17kX5XkvRMN%2BW89zA%2FUtaBoKcUH66KgtRlv1jNpvAVksipnMsdLthPS41%2BUMkEpvo%2FB22MTd%2FFtTMYZ6tVkX7Fg4eQa2M3Oxn0icMbf1T24bh8XWVVJHgNueE6vS1UFlYWUGkuzG6yfP3Nu6mdOHfw8QWJt98EfYPXd166HVVVi0eP8yPNgg8cRYkOghRAW8z7Gcdqs1%2FM85533XQ954w9rNE0upmsFMH30IW%2FMTcM0vMvZIn8zQ3c03dKutPVdB3b1MqSgmH4C1H4Gf3JDkyw%2FhmiC8yhu%2FXGIIeG2ZjA2oX7B5CwM0Zneh60%2FHCC4xvTLiY8K%2BmBIAx9Dus7X593vly%2Bpi4zKlBRe5JgaTiuFsSOXew6FUooJLjTDQUZk6kIuTUfH6REiK2lZK6gzJoBnsq55hjNpMuxzyy2tVQv6EW38TSoqmCjlDSmuwMvlHw%3D%3D%22%7D; _gali=lnkNextResultsPage",
    'authority': "api2.realtor.ca",
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
    'accept': "*/*",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': "?1",
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
    'origin': "https://www.realtor.ca",
    'sec-fetch-site': "same-site",
    'sec-fetch-mode': "cors",
    'sec-fetch-dest': "empty",
    'referer': "https://www.realtor.ca/",
    'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9"
    }

conn.request("POST", "/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

out = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))

results = out.get('Results')
for r in results:
    print(r.get('Id'), r.get('Property').get('Price'))

print(len(results))
```

Broken scrapy code with 403 error:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class RealtorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'realtor'
    allowed_domains = ['api2.realtor.ca']

    api = "https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post/"

    payload = "ZoomLevel=11&LatitudeMax=43.98268&LongitudeMax=-78.96028&LatitudeMin=43.43223&LongitudeMin=-79.79249&Sort=6-D&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&Currency=CAD&CurrentPage=1&ApplicationId=1&CultureId=1&Version=7.0&RecordsPerPage=200"

    headers = {
        'cookie': "gig_bootstrap_3_mrQiIl6ov44s2X3j6NGWVZ9SDDtplqV7WgdcyEpGYnYxl7ygDWPQHqQqtpSiUfko=gigya-pr_ver4; visid_incap_2271082=JLYUNoQeQ8aK7XCukUKVyLTR4GEAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAD5E9h/kC3MKXYFk8j751oC; reese84=3:kSScWfkGFsGrIfH0oClFcA==:7I6p2X8egFPYsN4vhOQSzcG+bY31pkxS/fXEEvP9k7YrM9pKJIRxaMywKm1+U1DhuZilDxW9dT97UvcEqz9H8d6b81yJvbuEOsNCc1hlGdVd3ZjT2uSjne23lT3z3KZ2lj0sxMQRKgafW63RLwfBQWtCgxWHMp9k338xzLwnTwqzOMI+qkBLPMwUolKoJP3IL6gzbljA6PY7Pyaa/R7VMRlGzcnk+M/ILnqZV8kJ+xV8sukeGZAcs4nJqJbvRr6vSE+fsAe/Jct5iAOnYTGoC+IyUdOAIWn2jEXTjwdjndvGdsKGvvkvcnkIjX1/JNTFH922HZPL3q9LzFCEgMhuYgygFRFjCqaz/HJ0zr0DXL9uTjiripD29T9lA0k0fGs+vyMz0ApV2Ni9UJsosr747CQMLROcZCQSIik2p+Taflc3cIAZgituGSiJss6o94xm:40hT11A7LacDXW+pa+D9sBQF5meDdTDqnBCeCZs/jls=; visid_incap_2269415=SnrfkV/xRM2/zMAwUwhS+8xj4GEAAAAAQkIPAAAAAACALOWhAWPmyCDb18oF6pHY12yEiWlUbIgr; nlbi_2269415=Vq3lX/59Tg3xXSVkkG5lugAAAAB+8mCpAlS1F5Timw4irGua; _gid=GA1.2.1583316853.1643415717; ASP.NET_SessionId=ov1iizcd3npobsilupzii5ep; nlbi_2271082=uYrYPyycJwjJZMEUcbDG1QAAAABYkXBfZhGO2s/HVfvOZarc; incap_ses_303_2269415=tkGkDvUztDFYLuufDHk0BPFK9WEAAAAAaFTGABendGhY7YQ6DfHGqg==; incap_ses_303_2271082=R007Dwk7akm7gfCfDHk0BPhS9WEAAAAAEzSDycWG9SwrHnLXWGiOuQ==; reese84=3:xy6Z/sx1YkpUszEJSoRL3A==:lovsunYlSfQpJkP59Bs11wY2+LlgzOMeiL3ObotvVpDwGDJVy4RKfSLLKuvVMLLcTstWzewelf4RKJ3e6v5hAVv9wkqa01hiSd1TIDBTDdyPzcKMI0xlq6r0G2P+8dMx91eZ0jKEx40QdURnU3XwLghg1BALZ+aWt4US7pC1FIftQksLhz7QlnyBw8pl2ucIJ9JIyuM3gBjNaP4hvYyc17UOnBvf37wtLhWeFb+fomUnnLqyTag5dM/vASoIg+Uo+lH9yQI2K9xGm0KveqgF2nUre9Z+UG1gwHWRBEIjygnhZZjnJOR20wxQU7gOZ8YqW+DJdczgSiqbn93I1um+VwOlf8bD6zCq99miEtaVOdVlGZesCvoe9d9JciEryAFMlYcn3RuLvycVNPQVrdCP9REneI+J1AmfXeSveEGpLhnSZs64rniGIf7iT0lRY9c1:f519Rour27xdzG5PjxP0BlHw/5uwjBdnwdY9Zd3AWpU=; nlbi_2269415_2147483646=5DLdcUXrjg0v1GhykG5lugAAAAA0AOEmZsShmR8VQ3d3LJzx; _dc_gtm_UA-12908513-11=1; _ga=GA1.2.2104488426.1642095581; _gac_UA-12908513-11=1.1643468700.Cj0KCQiA6NOPBhCPARIsAHAy2zAmFT3_yol1CanQDHoHW_z8aJ6HgaY2f7iilRt6yGvssuzmDbbh8FoaAkpxEALw_wcB; _ga_Y07J3B53QP=GS1.1.1643467388.20.1.1643468729.19; _4c_=%7B%22_4c_s_%22%3A%22bZNbj5swEIX%2FSuTnhfgKJm%2BrVKpWatWqUp8jgwdiLcHIOKHbKP%2B9Y3JZ7ap%2BAZ85%2BoxnDmcy72EgG1ZIIQtdCiGUfiKv8DaRzZkEZ9PjRDakrUBWitqsVIxmEjjNdNGYzIAxFFdbcUmeyJ%2BFVemSKc2oKi5PxA53hoXWHPt4tymqpZaSCS3Q5sZ486WPYVJrWWquH17kX5XkvRMN%2BW89zA%2FUtaBoKcUH66KgtRlv1jNpvAVksipnMsdLthPS41%2BUMkEpvo%2FB22MTd%2FFtTMYZ6tVkX7Fg4eQa2M3Oxn0icMbf1T24bh8XWVVJHgNueE6vS1UFlYWUGkuzG6yfP3Nu6mdOHfw8QWJt98EfYPXd166HVVVi0eP8yPNgg8cRYkOghRAW8z7Gcdqs1%2FM85533XQ954w9rNE0upmsFMH30IW%2FMTcM0vMvZIn8zQ3c03dKutPVdB3b1MqSgmH4C1H4Gf3JDkyw%2FhmiC8yhu%2FXGIIeG2ZjA2oX7B5CwM0Zneh60%2FHCC4xvTLiY8K%2BmBIAx9Dus7X593vly%2Bpi4zKlBRe5JgaTiuFsSOXew6FUooJLjTDQUZk6kIuTUfH6REiK2lZK6gzJoBnsq55hjNpMuxzyy2tVQv6EW38TSoqmCjlDSmuwMvlHw%3D%3D%22%7D; _gali=lnkNextResultsPage",
        'authority': "api2.realtor.ca",
        'sec-ch-ua': '" Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="97", "Chromium";v="97"',
        'accept': "*/*",
        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': "?1",
        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Mobile Safari/537.36",
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
        'origin': "https://www.realtor.ca",
        'sec-fetch-site': "same-site",
        'sec-fetch-mode': "cors",
        'sec-fetch-dest': "empty",
        'referer': "https://www.realtor.ca/",
        'accept-language': "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        }

    def start_requests(self):
        
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.api,
                        callback=self.parse,
                        method='POST', 
                        headers=self.headers,
                        body=json.dumps(self.payload) )  

    def parse(self, response):
        print('PARSE')
        results = json.loads(response.body).get('Results')
        print('results')
        for r in results:
            yield {
                'Id': r.get('Id'),
                'Price': r.get('Property').get('Price')
            }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

    SPIDER_NAME = RealtorSpider.name
    try:
        execute(
            [
                'scrapy',
                'crawl',
                SPIDER_NAME,
                '-s',
                'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING=utf-8',
            ]
        )
    except SystemExit:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have an excess `/` in the url. Remove it to avoid 404 error.
2. You don't need `json.dumps` since `payload` is already a string.
3. Let scrapy handle the cookies itself.
4. I guess that your headers are wrong because after changing them I don't get 403 status anymore.
5. See how to [run scrapy from a script](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

spider.py:

```py
import scrapy


class RealtorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'realtor'
    allowed_domains = ['api2.realtor.ca']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.5,
    }
    api = "https://api2.realtor.ca/Listing.svc/PropertySearch_Post"

    payload = "ZoomLevel=11&LatitudeMax=43.98268&LongitudeMax=-78.96028&LatitudeMin=43.43223&LongitudeMin=-79.79249&Sort=6-D&PropertySearchTypeId=1&TransactionTypeId=2&PropertyTypeGroupID=1&Currency=CAD&CurrentPage=1&ApplicationId=1&CultureId=1&Version=7.0&RecordsPerPage=200"

    headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "api2.realtor.ca",
        "Origin": "https://www.realtor.ca",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Referer": "https://www.realtor.ca/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "TE": "trailers",
        'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    }
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.api,
                             callback=self.parse,
                             method='POST',
                             headers=self.headers,
                             body=self.payload)

    def parse(self, response):
        print('PARSE')
        results = response.json().get('Results')
        print('results')
        for r in results:
            yield {
                'Id': r.get('Id'),
                'Price': r.get('Property').get('Price')
            }
```

main.py:

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'realtor'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

output:

```py
{'Id': '23983739', 'Price': '$799,000'}
{'Id': '23983759', 'Price': '$579,000'}
{'Id': '23983752', 'Price': '$750,000'}
...
...
...
```

Comment: Thanks. How did you know what to change the headers to? You mentioned you removed the cookies. But yours also have other differences.

Comment: I still get the 403 after 2 mins of running my script

Comment: I copied the headers from inside devtools in the browser. You only have one request so if it downloaded with status 200 then that's it. Do you run the spider more than once?

Comment: yes, I tried running it a few times